# Burninate very specific tag [getgenerictype]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [getgenerictype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getgenerictype) tag is very specific, it's actually a method of the Java [`Field`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getGenericType--) class, and it has only 3 questions, let's kill it before it lays more eggs.

We don't want to have a tag for each method in the world; [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and [generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generics) are enough to describe questions about generics in Java.

Comment: How does it fit the criteria stated in https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191 ?

Comment: @DeerHunter So will if be fine if I now add `isSynthetic`, `toGenericString` and other tag-methods? Sometimes it just feels that the tag shouldn't be there.

Comment: May be ok, but you'd better show your reasoning according to criteria in the above-mentioned answer by Shog9.

Comment: Relevant discussion started: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316066/should-all-burninate-requests-follow-a-template

Comment: @DeerHunter Even if it doesn't meet any criteria of this post.. I still think it should be burninated.

Comment: Up to you, actually. Some people create content, some people curate it, and some are content to delete what others created.

Comment: Specific generic? Either the one or the other, but not both :) However I see what you mean and I totally agree.

Comment: @HimBromBeere that's the pun here.. I guess it's a bad one ;)

Comment: @DeerHunter It's not unambiguous (criterion 1), since there's no way to tell from looking at the tag that it has anything to do with Java or the `Field` class. It adds no meaningful information to questions (criterion 3), since any question about a specific method that doesn't actually mention that method in the body of the question would make no sense. It could conceivably mean other things in other contexts (criterion 4), since (for example) a C++ programmer might think it has something to do with type-inference techniques.

Answer (score 26):

Since it's only three questions, I went ahead and did the deed:

- [Java, define a method test( ArrayList<Object> list ), but when call test(new ArrayList<String>) can't be compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35172792/java-define-a-method-test-arraylistobject-list-but-when-call-testnew-arr)

  Changed [getgenerictype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getgenerictype) to [generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generics)
- [Simple framework XML binding with generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28625704/simple-framework-xml-binding-with-generic-types)

  Changed [getgenerictype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getgenerictype) to [generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generics)
- [Field.getGenericType() returns instance of java.lang.Class instead of Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072703/field-getgenerictype-returns-instance-of-java-lang-class-instead-of-type)

  Changed [getgenerictype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getgenerictype) to [generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generics)