# Are tags that are too specific considered harmful (and potentially burninate-worthy) in the same way as tags that are too broad?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-system

Let's take [unsigned-long-long-int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unsigned-long-long-int) as an example. It has under 200 questions and no watchers, so it's not in high demand; but that hasn't stopped it from being (mis)applied to any question that contains anything about "long long".

[The Help Centre states:](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

> A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question.

Just because the problem occurs when using a specific datatype, does not mean the problem is about that datatype - most of the questions I've perused that use this tag "correctly", are actually basic integer overflow issues.

Therefore, in my books, this tag is actually harmful. It's being applied incorrectly **and** it doesn't help anyone to find the questions it's applied to, so it feels like nothing more than noise. As such I'm strongly in favour of removing it, but of course it would fail the burnination checklist.

What is Meta's opinion on incredibly specific tags like these? Should they stay, or go?

Comment: From [What is the process for tag removal (burnination)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/11682469): "If a particular tag is bringing lots of off-topic posts to the site, then it certainly is harmful." Does this also apply to [tag:unsigned-long-long-int]?

Comment: I don't think they're harmful, but I think they (including all *View *Exception *Listener tags) should go.

Comment: If it doesn't fulfill the purpose "of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories" why have it? For giggles?

Comment: Clearly stay as they are used for the purpose

Comment: There does seem to be [precedent](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316063) for burninating overly specific tags. Though, in that case there were 3 questions, so the process was easy. I'm not convinced that a tag being too specific is enough reason to get rid of it.

Comment: I don't think "too specific" is good metric, or a good description of the type of tag you mention. The bar to pass is always the same: does the tag help in describing the question, and making the question easier to find by experts? Can there be experts in the subject matter described by the tag? ["Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). Personally, I don't believe that this tag passes muster, but that does not mean it's worth our time burninating it.

Comment: @yivi If there's a problem of time, maybe we should ask for better tooling.

Comment: it's not worth the time to build such tooling for a problem that isn't actually a problem.

Comment: @KevinB wait what? Removing tags is not a problem? Remember, the tooling will be available to be used in any circumstance. Are we really going that way? We need to remove [web], [hypen]. [social] and such tooling would help with that.

Answer (score 6):

No.

Tags that are too specific (or tags that are too broad) are not harmful by themselves. It is the wrong tag usage that causes an inundation of posts for specific subject matter experts to focus on the questions they want to answer.

A tag is an informal, free of process, labeling system and it is wise to keep it that way.

The main goal of a tag is to bring a question in front of subject matter experts (SME) that can answer it. If those subject matter experts find those questions due to a highly specialized but not often used tag then the tag fulfills its task.

A tag only becomes problematic when it's not easily found or doesn't help in filtering answerable questions to a manageable set.

If an SME feels a tag is valid by itself but may be better served by a similarly applicable but overarching tag, consider a synonym. That keeps the tag available for askers but does bring those questions to more users that are willing to answer them.

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily, but it subverts the purpose of tags. Tags needs two characteristics:

- connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer
- sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories

Note that the help center expounds on this further

> you should only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question covers a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site.

So, it's a multi-step process:

- Overly specific tags where there is another tag that already covers it, makes them redundant.
- Overly generic tags make it more difficult for experts to connect with the questions.

Since tags should have a purpose before being created, and the tag creator should abstain from creating them in the first place, I think our thinking is backwards. It's not if the tag is causing harm, it's whether it's benefiting anyone by existing.

Comment: "It's not if the tag is causing harm, it's whether it's benefiting anyone by existing." Exactly this. Meta's consensus seems to be that if it isn't obviously causing harm it should be left alone, but the broken windows theory very obviously torpedoes this argument.